# Javascript check if left mouse button is clicked

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, mouse, mouseleftbuttondown

I have this code to detect mouse down. However on android phones, mouse down for a long time often converts to a right click.
Is there a way I can only get information about left mouse click?

```
var mouseDown = 0;
document.body.onmousedown = function() { 
  ++mouseDown;
}
document.body.onmouseup = function() {
  --mouseDown;
}
```

using this as the code below

```
if (mouseDown){
xyz happens
}
```

Still a beginner, please tell me what to change in both the codes.

Thanks

Comment: Just check `onmousedown = function(e) { 
 e.button;
}`, 1 left 2 middle 3 right

Comment: Phones generally have their own tap events, but with a regular mouse you'd just check if `event.which === 1`

Comment: why don't you use the touchstart and touchend events  instead of mouse down or  mouse up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).mousedown(function(e) {
      if (e.which === 1) {
          alert("left");
      }else if(e.which === 3){
          alert("right");
      }
  });

});
```

Comment: Not Javascript :(

Comment: `which` is deprecated, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/which